# How to make IK target bone undetachable?

Tags: animation, bones, inverse-kinematics

So I have a arm, and a IK. The target bone of the IK is called wrist. My goal is to make the wrist bone undetachable from the IK bone.

[image]

This is what I don't want. The wrist bone (purple one, is detached from the yellow IK arm bone. I want to make the bone unable to detach. And always stay like this.

[image].

Comment: I think you should parent the palm bone to the target bone (in keep offset mode), but the hand will detach from the arm, not a big problem though

Comment: Then the target bone will still be detached from the arm.
What I want: when IK is fully extended, the target can't move away from the arm bone any farther, because that will actually move the arm bone since the arm will always be facing the targer.

Comment: yes I know, it doesn't give a full solution, I don't know if what you ask is possible as it generates parentage conflicts

Comment: I am trying to make my sword move as horizontal as possible, I don't want is to bounce up and down because that is not how you swing a sword.
Since my sword it controlled by one of my hand bones, and hand bones are all moving with the arm, I want to make my arm as stable as possible.

Comment: Do you understand what I mean when I say "when IK is fully extended, the target can't move away from the arm bone any farther, because that will actually move the arm bone since the arm will always be facing the target.", because I am not sure I described it well.

Comment: maybe show some screenshots or share just the armature: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/